# 異なるページ内のJavascriptを実行する

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

以下のような閲覧ページ(index.html)があります。

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <title>Notification</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script src='https://cdn.rawgit.com/jaredreich/notie.js/a9e4afbeea979c0e6ee50aaf5cb4ee80e65d225d/notie.js'></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      notie.alert(1, '通知', 10);
    };
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

今は通知を表示する以下のメソッドがページのロード完了時に実行されるようになっていますが、
これを別の管理用のページ(例:admin.html)から任意のタイミングで呼び出すことは可能でしょうか？

```
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      notie.alert(1, '通知', 10);
    };
  </script>
```

Comment: 閲覧ページと管理ページは同一のユーザの同一のブラウザの違うタブ(ウィンドウ)で表示する前提でしょうか? それとも、全く異なるユーザ?

Comment: 閲覧ページは不特定のユーザーが閲覧します。要約すると、「ユーザーが閲覧中のページに任意のタイミングで通知を表示したい」ということです。

Answer (score 1):

index.htmlを参照するiframeを任意のタイミングで生成すれば呼び出せます。
↓任意のタイミングで下記のような関数を呼び出すイメージです。

```
function call_it(){
  $(”<iframe src='index.html' />”).appendTo(”body”);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

大雑把には、

admin.htmlはユーザ認証されているものとして、admin.htmlから何らかの手段でサーバに「ユーザに通知せよ」というリクエストを送る。

サーバは上記リクエストで「通知する必要あり」という状態を保持する。

サーバが通知をブラウザにプッシュする。WebSocketで本当にプッシュする、HTTPのポーリングで擬似プッシュするなど。